# ffmpeg: File not found, but obviously is accessible

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, filesystems, file-permissions

Either I'm doing some very stupid mistake, or I've stumbled upon a very strange bug here. I'm in bash, and I want to convert a .flac to a .mp3 using ffmpeg. Running

```
ffmpeg -i 3\ -\ Thirty\ Seconds\ to\ Mars\ -\ Rescue\ Me.flac 3\ -\ Thirty\ Seconds\ to\ Mars\ -\ Rescue\ Me.mp3
```

results in `3 - Thirty Seconds to Mars - Rescue Me.flac: No such file or directory`, although `stat` and `ls` both show the file with read permissions for the current user, and I can even view its contents using `less`.

I suspected a problem with the filename, so I renamed the file to `asdf.flac`, which worked, but `ffmpeg -i asdf.flac asdf.mp3` still gives me `asdf.flac: No such file or directory`.

To exclude permission issues, I already did `chmod -R 777 .` to make the directory and all files world-readable and world-writable, still no chance.

Any ideas what could cause ffmpeg to not find the file, although it's obviously there?

Comment: What is the output of `type ffmpeg`? If it returns a path, what is the output of `file /the/path/to/ffmpeg`? Is there something quirky about the filesystem? (e.g. FUSE).

Comment: The only way I can think that this would occur is if `ffmpeg` has the set user/group ID permission. What does `ls -l $(which ffmpeg)` report?

Comment: Maybe it's something weird in the filename. Can you rename the source to something simple and try operating on that?

Comment: @wef Please re-read the question: "I suspected a problem with the filename, so I renamed the file to asdf.flac, which worked, but ffmpeg -i asdf.flac asdf.mp3 still gives me asdf.flac: No such file or directory."

Comment: Whoops - seriously didn't notice that. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kamil-maciorowski pointed me to the right direction.

```
lukas@Server:~$ type ffmpeg
ffmpeg ist /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

Which reminded me of a `firejail` setup.

```
lukas@Server:~$ file /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: symbolic link to /usr/bin/firejail
```

Confirmed this. So apparently `ffmpeg` is running in a jail. Didn't know that I had `firejail` set up on that machine, but running `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` directly worked. So there is a restriction of the jail present, that doesn't whitelist input files.